# Laravel import PDF with editable fields and fill same fields with data

Tags: laravel, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I am trying to import a certain PDF file that has editable fields, fill it with data from my database and then download it and keep those fields editable again when accessing that pdf file. Can somebody help me with first steps of how I should approach this problem? 
Thanks in advance to all

Answer (score 0):

You can use **TCPDF** or **FPDF** with the **FPDI** extension to modify PDF **the result is a new PDF file in this case it will be ideal create new one PDF from uploaded PDF and editables fields**.

To install FPDF + FPDI in Laravel you just need to run:

```
composer require setasign/fpdf && composer require setasign/fpdi
```

- or check : https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI and https://github.com/Setasign/FPDF
- make yourself comfortable with FPDF and FPDI documentation https://manuals.setasign.com/

Comment: Thanks Kais for your response. Will try and let you know